# Using Dynamic and enforcing WCF contract upon Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have two model classes `IntroModel` and `PhonePageModel`. These are both WCF contracts.

I'm calling an API that gives back JSON and lets say I have stored it in string format.

`String myApiData = myAPI.getTodaysInfo();`

Using a function enum parameter, I would like to deserialize into the correct type of model

```
IntroPageModel introPageModel = null;
PhonePageModel phonePageModel = null;

if (enumVal == myEnums.IntroPage)
{
    introPageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IntroPageModel>(myApiData);
}
else if (enumVal == myEnums.PhonePageModel)
{
    phonePageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhonePageModel>(myApiData);
}
```

This leaves the problem later in my code though of checking which model isn't null to know which model to work with afterwards. Instead, could I use dynamic but still ensure the information from `myApiData` is validated properly based upon the correct WCF Page model?

```
dynamic myPageModel = null;

if (enumVal == myEnums.IntroPage)
{
    myPageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IntroPageModel>(myApiData);
}
else if (enumVal == myEnums.PhonePageModel)
{
    myPageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhonePageModel>(myApiData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that you your get todayinfo as result array than object it will be something like this:

```
[
[
  {
    "IntroModelid": 1,
    "IntroModelname": "intro123",
    "guid": "151512321312",
    "introModelfunc": [
      {
        "funcid": 1,
        "funcname": "func123"
      }
    ]
  }
],
[
  {
    "PhonePageModelid": 1,
    "PhonePageModelname": "phone123",
    "other": "other",
    "phonenumers": [
      {
        "numersid": 1,
        "numbers": 6789,
        "status": "OK"
      },
      {
        "numersid": 2,
        "numbers": 12345,
        "funcionamiento": "NO"
      }
    ]
  }
]
]
```

when you get your collection as this:

```
var myapidata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myApiDataString);
```

you will have two ChildrenTokens = Count = 2

you can iterate this as you wish. Or you can pass to your class list

```
                var myapidata = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                var IntroPageModel = myapidata [0];
                var PhonePageModel = myapidata [1];
```

Hope you find useful

Comment: try to read this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm